# SQL find car dealerships selling only one type of car

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find car dealerships that only sell cars of one type. I have a table `car` containing the `carid`, the `dealership` where the car is, the `engine` the car has and what `type` the car is (which can only be one of 4 types: sedan,coupe,hatchback,sports).

I know how to group by dealerships but I don't understand how to only find dealerships that have cars of only one type.
Here is what I have so far:

```
select carid,dealership,type from car group by dealership
```

Now my inital idea was to group by both `dealership` and `type` but that didn't find dealerships with cars of only one type as it gave me multiple results for some dealerships.

Then I tried to add a separate having clause like `having type='sedan'` for each type and then make a union of all the tables but that gave the same thing as the idea to group by both fields.

Comment: hint - `count()` and `having()`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about using count at all. I think I have it now I used: having count(distinct type) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Having to check the equality of the maximum and minimum values.

```
select dealership, Max(type) 
from car 
group by dealership
Having Max(type)=Min(type)
```